# Cannot paste in Visual Studio 2019 when debug in command prompt

Tags: c#, debugging

I have some strange issue.Yesterday i had to install new visual studio 2019.Today i'm doing some stuff and when try to debug some code and i had to put some large input and try to paste it, i cannot.I try with right click on window>edit>paste but still wont work.Any ideas what happend?

Comment: In debug mode, visual studio never allowed you to paste anything in .cs files.

Comment: @Jabberwocky [Edit and Continue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/edit-and-continue?view=vs-2019) is real. But I don't think OP is referring to .cs files; rather he's talking about the command window itself.

Comment: in visual studio 2017 worked pretty well, but now cannot.

Comment: Try 32bit instead of 64bit.  64bit doesn't allow editing of source code while running in the debugger.   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/habibh/2009/10/12/how-to-edit-code-when-debugging-a-64-bit-application/